# Repeat formula based on dynamic range or matrix formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm creating a set of formulas to analyze different sets of json data. I would like to show the uniqueness for each field in the dataset and the top 3 values per field. The json data is pasted on one of the sheets, and the results of my analyses are shown on a different sheet.

An example of some arbitrary raw data:

[image]

For this dataset I can create the following formulas (all similar coloured cells are matrix formulas):

[image]

Cell A1 contains a formula that dynamically returns all headers (yellow). If the pasted data contains more fields, this list expands automatically. The pink area also grows or shrinks based on the amount of records and fields in the raw data.

What I would like to know is how to setup the following formulas:

- Row 2: Return if the values are either all unique, or how many variations are there within each column. I allready have the formula for a single column, but I would like a matrix formula so that it automatically grows or shrinks as well.
- Row 3 to 5: Return the top 3 of values within each column.

An example of the header formula (yellow):

```
=LET(SUB,INDIRECT("A8:"&ADDRESS(8,number_of_fields)),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTRING(SUB,1,FIND(":",SUB)-1),"""","")
```

*(formula translated from dutch syntax)*

I know how to manually copy the formulas over, but I'm sure it's possible to convert this into a matrix formula. For example, is there a function like Repeat, but for formulas repeating for x amount of cells?

Edit after answer: Getting close! The top 3 is almost working as intended. The answer below creates the following result on a more complex dataset:
[image]

It sometimes leaves a cell empty in the top 3 for that column. Preferably the top 3 values bubble up to the top, where it populates row 2 and 3 if the column only contains 2 variations.

Comment: Do you have access to `TEXTSPLIT` (`TEKST.SPLITSEN()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a little too literal, but the following formula will spill the top 3 and the splitted data as shown in the picture

```
=LET(data,TRIM(Sheet1!A1:A9),
     f,FILTER(data,LEFT(data,1)=""""),
     split,DROP(REDUCE(0,f,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,",")))),1),
     header,SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(split,1),":"),"""",""),
     s,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(split)),
     count,DROP(REDUCE(0,s,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(split,,b))=INDEX(split,,b)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(f),,1,0))))),,1),
     comb,split&" ("&count&")",
     allunique,DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,s,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,UNIQUE(INDEX(comb,,b))))),""),,1),
     fq,DROP(REDUCE(0,s,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,ROWS(f)-FREQUENCY(XMATCH(INDEX(split,,b),INDEX(split,,b)),XMATCH(INDEX(split,,b),INDEX(split,,b)))))),-1,1),
     _top3,TAKE(REDUCE(0,s,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,SORTBY(INDEX(allunique,,b),INDEX(fq,,b),1)))),3,-COLUMNS(split)),
IFERROR(VSTACK(header,_top3,"","",split),""))
```

`split` is all data (below),
`_top3` is the top 3 of the frequency of the text per column.

[image]

You may only need the `_top3` data though..

If I'm not mistaken, this would be the Dutch variant:

```
=LET(data;SPATIES.WISSEN(A1:A9);
f;FILTER(data;LINKS(data;1)="""");
split;WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1);
header;SUBSTITUEREN(TEKST.SPLITSEN(NEMEN(WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1);1);":");"""";"");
s;REEKS(1;KOLOMMEN(WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1)));
count;WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;s;LAMBDA(a;b;HOR.STAPELEN(a;PRODUCTMAT(--(TRANSPONEREN(INDEX(WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1);;b))=INDEX(WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1);;b));REEKS(RIJEN(f);;1;0)))));;1);
comb;split&" ("&count&")";
allunique;WEGLATEN(ALS.FOUT(REDUCE(0;s;LAMBDA(a;b;HOR.STAPELEN(a;UNIEK(INDEX(comb;;b)))));"");;1);
fq;WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;s;LAMBDA(a;b;HOR.STAPELEN(a;RIJEN(f)-INTERVAL(X.VERGELIJKEN(INDEX(split;;b);INDEX(split;;b));X.VERGELIJKEN(INDEX(split;;b);INDEX(split;;b))))));-1;1);
_top3;NEMEN(REDUCE(0;s;LAMBDA(a;b;HOR.STAPELEN(a;SORTEREN.OP(INDEX(allunique;;b);INDEX(fq;;b);1))));3;-KOLOMMEN(split));
ALS.FOUT(VERT.STAPELEN(header;_top3;"";"";split);""))
```

(I'm Dutch, but I'm not familiar with the Dutch equivalents of the newer functions, since I work with English version and support is contradicting in some times:
`NEMEN` might be `TAKE`, since it's listed as `NEMEN` here https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/office/excel-functies-alfabetisch-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188#bm14, but if you click for it, it shows explanation for `TAKE` in Dutch (https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/office/take-functie-25382ff1-5da1-4f78-ab43-f33bd2e4e003) ).

Edit:
To "drop" the trailing boolean column you can add another condition to `DROP` (`WEGLATEN`):

`WEGLATEN([data],1,-1)` this means dropping the first row of the data (condition `1`) and it's last column (condition `-1`):

```
=LET(data;SPATIES.WISSEN(A1:A9);
f;FILTER(data;LINKS(data;1)="""");
split;WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1;-1);
header;SUBSTITUEREN(TEKST.SPLITSEN(NEMEN(WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1);1);":");"""";"");
s;REEKS(1;KOLOMMEN(WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1)));
count;WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;s;LAMBDA(a;b;HOR.STAPELEN(a;PRODUCTMAT(--(TRANSPONEREN(INDEX(WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1);;b))=INDEX(WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;f;LAMBDA(a;b;VERT.STAPELEN(a;TEKST.SPLITSEN(b;","))));1);;b));REEKS(RIJEN(f);;1;0)))));;1);
comb;split&" ("&count&")";
allunique;WEGLATEN(ALS.FOUT(REDUCE(0;s;LAMBDA(a;b;HOR.STAPELEN(a;UNIEK(INDEX(comb;;b)))));"");;1);
fq;WEGLATEN(REDUCE(0;s;LAMBDA(a;b;HOR.STAPELEN(a;RIJEN(f)-INTERVAL(X.VERGELIJKEN(INDEX(split;;b);INDEX(split;;b));X.VERGELIJKEN(INDEX(split;;b);INDEX(split;;b))))));-1;1);
_top3;NEMEN(REDUCE(0;s;LAMBDA(a;b;HOR.STAPELEN(a;SORTEREN.OP(INDEX(allunique;;b);INDEX(fq;;b);1))));3;-KOLOMMEN(split));
ALS.FOUT(VERT.STAPELEN(header;_top3;"";"";split);""))
```

And to cope with columns where there's less than 3 top ranked values:

```
=LET(data,TRIM(Sheet1!A1:A9),
f,FILTER(data,LEFT(data,1)=""""),
split,DROP(REDUCE(0,f,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,",")))),1),
header,SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(split,1),":"),"""",""),
s,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(split)),
count,DROP(REDUCE(0,s,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(split,,b))=INDEX(split,,b)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(f),,1,0))))),,1),
comb,split&" ("&count&")",
allunique,DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,s,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,UNIQUE(INDEX(comb,,b))))),""),,1),
fq,DROP(REDUCE(0,s,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,ROWS(f)-FREQUENCY(XMATCH(INDEX(split,,b),INDEX(split,,b)),XMATCH(INDEX(split,,b),INDEX(split,,b)))))),-1,1),
_top3,TAKE(REDUCE(0,s,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,SORTBY(INDEX(allunique,,b),INDEX(fq,,b),1)))),3,-COLUMNS(split)),
_top3minus,DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,s,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,FILTER(INDEX(_top3,,b),INDEX(_top3,,b)<>"")))),""),,1),
IFERROR(VSTACK(header,_top3minus,"","",split),""))
```

Comment: Amazing stuff, The top 3 was indeed one of the solutions I was looking for. My raw data contained some leading spaces and VERT.STAPELEN was misspelled in your example, but other than that it works like a charm. Thank you very much (Bedankt!!)
I added a boolean field in the raw data, which as expected adds a 5th column in all your formulas. In the top 3 however, the sorting for this data splits the 'yes' and 'no' values by a blank cell inbetween. Any idea how to ignore this cell in the sorting?

Comment: Above sorting has to do with the fact that the first 'no' is on my 3rd record. If I put the first 'no' in the 2nd record, it puts the empty cell on position 3 in the top 3, not between the 'yes' 'no'

Comment: If I understand it correctly see my edit. If there are more trailing columns, simply increase the last (negative) condition of `DROP`

Comment: The amount of columns is perfect. I have added a new screenshot at the bottom of my initial question to show the 'issue' I still have. I've tried a few filters and sorts here and there to try and fix it, but without luck

Comment: Could you share some of the raw data (or similar sample) that you think may cause this. I get the desired results with the sample data from the question. I don't know what the complexer data may consist of.

Comment: If I use data that contain 2 different options only it shows them from top to bottom. Since the 3rd is non-existent it will be blank, but never on top, or in the middle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvfgL.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249654/discussion-between-jan-willem-and-p-b).